# Get AWS Account ID using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can I get the  [`AWS Account ID`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html) using `awscli`?

I look for something like

```
$ aws <service> <options>
123456789012
```

Close, but not what I'm looking for: `$ aws iam get-user`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following command returns the account number:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text
```

Command details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html)

(reformat the command as code session)

Answer (score 5):

Need to get an AWS Account ID from the aws cli tool? Here you go:

`aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account'`